# Preferred way of showing images in XAML from resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a .xaml file with a ResourceDictionary containing all my custom icons.

e.g.:

```
<Canvas x:Key="imgFoo" Width="16" Height="16">
    <Path Fill="#FFFF0000" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="#FFFF0000" StrokeMiterLimit="4" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M 2.0722892 ..... 4.0457831" FillRule="NonZero"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Now the question: what is the best way to use this resource in xaml?

Is it for example like this:

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource imgFoo}" />
            <TextBlock Text="Foo" />
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
```

Is using a ContentControl the correct way of using and displaying this resource?

**Update:**
and what about this method of using a drawingbrush and a border. Is this a good way?

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="imgF00">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing>
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen Thickness="3" MiterLimit="4" LineJoin="Round" StartLineCap="Round" EndLineCap="Round" Brush="#FFFF0000" />
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M 2.0722892 ... 4.0457831" FillRule="NonZero" />
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

showing it via a border:

```
 <TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Border Background="{StaticResource imgFail2}" Width="16" Height="16" />
            <TextBlock Text="Failure" />
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
```

Comment: Are the Path properties (Fill, Stroke, StrokeThickness, ...) the same for all icons in your application? Or do you have at least a small set of certain icon Path property combinations?

Comment: Anyway, you should avoid to use UI elements as resources. You might either use the PathGeometry as resource, or if each icon has different Fill and Stroke etc, perhaps use a GeometryDrawing.

Comment: currently my drawings are paths in a canvas as shown here...

Comment: Currently your drawings are paths in canvases. Well, I can see that. And I wouldn't recommend to do that, because a Canvas is a UI element, which should usually not be used as resource. What about my question?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly. 
I just have bitmap images (.png / .jpg) and would like to use some images created via xaml. These are defined in a .xaml file as a ResourceDictionary and is loaded in the App.xaml as a global resource so that I can use the icons on several controls/usercontrols.

Comment: The question was, are the Path properties (Fill, Stroke, StrokeThickness, ...) the same for all icons in your application? If yes, I'd recommend you a more elegant solution that yours, but it depends on what you answer...

Comment: every icon has its own strokethickness, stroke-color, different miterlimit,.. set, because they are individually designed.

Comment: you can use this approach also to show path data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22802503/how-can-i-set-wpfs-image-source-property-to-canvas-instead-of-image-url/22805942#22805942

Comment: That is exactly what I am recommending in my answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using UI elements (like Canvas an Path) as icon resources, you may use `DrawingBrush` objects like this:

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="imgFoo" ViewboxUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,16,16">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFF0000">
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen Thickness="3" Brush="#FFFF0000" MiterLimit="4" LineJoin="Round" StartLineCap="Round" EndLineCap="Round"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="..." FillRule="NonZero"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

You may now use such a Brush for e.g. the Fill property of a Rectangle:

```
<TabItem.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource imgFoo}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Foo" />
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem.Header>
```

Comment: does it make a difference to use a border or a rectangle? (performance, memory usage, ... ?)

Comment: No, there is no significant difference. A Rectangle may be considered more light-weight because it can't have a child element.

Comment: Perfect, too bad there are no good resources on how to do this the "correct" way :-)

Comment: Perhaps because there is not really a correct way. It really depends on how your icon look like, i.e. if they all have different colors and line thicknesses, or if they are simple pictogram that are only filled.